# Archiva deployment on wildfly 10

Tags: jboss, archiva

I have the following problem when i try to deploy archiva 2.2.1 on wildfly 10.
Can someone help me to resolve it ?

```
Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "operation" => "deploy",
    "address" => [("deployment" => "archiva.war")]
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.archiva.archiva.env.mail.Session is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.mail.Session]"]},
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the JNDI name in your `WEB-INF/web.xml` file in the archiva JAR.

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>mail/Session</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.mail.Session</res-type>
  <jndi-name>java:jboss/mail/Default</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```

You can find the JNDI name by referring to the `standalone/configurations/standalone-full.xml`.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:2.0">
    <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
        <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
    </mail-session>
</subsystem>
```

Note the JNDI name of the mail session is `java:jboss/mail/Default`.